# Can not install a "Launcher" app on Android Box device

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I am developing an Android app which has the `android.intent.category.HOME` intent filter in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The same app installs without an issue on a spare Android 7 device that I have in hand, but won't install on my Android 9 TV Box -- until I remove the said intent filter from the manifest.

I'm getting an **`INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED`** failure on ADB, with the following message:

> Don't allow install The third Launcher

I guess the exception somehow comes from the [`PackageParser.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java), but I don't know where exactly.

If I remove the launcher (i.e. HOME) intent filter from my manifest file, the app installs successfully without any failures.

Looking through similar SO answers yielded no results, and Google suggests issues with OEM builds.

The question is, how can I investigate and solve this issue?

---

**UPDATE:** I can confirm that this limitation is sadly put into effect by the Chinese device manufacturer.

P.S. This seems to be a common issue with these Android TV boxes, found [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android-stick--console-computers/amlogic/h96-pro-launcher-issue-t3676808) and [here](https://forums.androidcentral.com/android-tv/916680-unable-run-nova-launcher-android-tv-box.html).

Also, as a workaround, if I manually replace the installed `/data/app/*.apk` file with another build that *has* the HOME intent filter, the application can work as a launcher just fine. This actually shows that the issue is with the PackageParser, not the installation itself.

Comment: Given that error message, I put very high probability of it being a limitation put in place by your Android TV box manufacturer. The solution, at best, is to get a different Android TV box, if you want to replace its `HOME` implementation. If you are willing to skip `HOME` for the Android TV box, but you would like to have the rest of the app work, you could have `tv` and `mobile` product flavors, where the `HOME` manifest entry (and perhaps the activity and related code) are only in `mobile`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I also suspect the limitation is made by the manufacturer, but I'd like to see if I can somehow bypass it. I need to leverage the `HOME` intent in my app. +1 for your comment